# Kubernetes many restarts but pod keeps running

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I'm seeing a lot of restarts on all the pods of every service that I have deployed on Kubernetes.

But when I see the logs in real time:

```
kubectl -n my-namespace logs -c my-pod -f my-pod-some-hash --tail=50
```

I see nothing, there's no restarts, there's no signal of failure. Readiness keep workings. So what it means all those restarts? Where or how can I get more info about those restarts?

[image]

Edit:

By viewing the pod details of the pod that has 158 on the picture above, I can see this, but I don't know what it means or if it's related to the restarts:

[image]

Comment: Please use "--Previous" tag to get the logs of Pod.  syntax:    kubectl logs <PodName> --previous

Answer (score 1):

**Replication via one sample example pod with CLI commands**

If any pod restarts, in order to check the logs of the previous run user "**--previous**"

Step1:
Connect to cluster using below command

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group <resourcegroupname> --name <Clustername>
```

Step2:
verify the pod logs

```
kubectl get pods
```

[image]
Step3:
Verify the restart pods logs using command

```
kubectl logs <PodName> --previous
```

[image]